# Facebook Conversion API not receiving events on live event

Tags: facebook

I am sending an event to Facebook Conversion API. It sends fine when using the 'test_event_code' => 'TEST11781'. I receive it al ok in event manager. However, when I remove that test_event_code attribute, ie to make the event live, I am not receiving the events in event manager. Here is the json event code being sent. Any ideas why it sends to the test event but not the live event? Thanks.

```html
{
    "data": [
        {
            "event_name": "ViewContent",
            "event_source_url": "https://www.domain.co.uk/",
            "event_time": 1638201564,
            "action_source": "website",
            "user_data": {
                "client_ip_address": "78.xxx.xx.79",
                "client_user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36",
                "em": "bee8327d3be983b71f5c3665225dd24b305362943e81738ec639e2b418c64d68",
                "ph": "3e3d1c86840255608723f4a7e667f7482de0a877376347232336da4dec0fc6a1",
                "ge": "62c66a7a5dd70c3146618063c344e531e6d4b59e379808443ce962b3abd63c5a",
                "ln": "a9cca5a75f06071ab13f05f8b017500014117c4022414cdfb7439ca332ccecbd",
                "fn": "dbadfc88144b0c153a2d1bdf154681c857a237eb79d58df24e918bca6e17db05",
                "ct": "b11c0468e61792336d6c0fca278f850aee8ab9e9d7d0df03e070df82b02188c8",
                "st": "1de408006eb5a879c99e8ccda85bf7bcc72f1a22c9693fa7ef9fafec80e21b82",
                "zp": "102ee65281e730945c8de2678fdb0659ddcf732c2a638c7f80f5322168726dad",
                "country": "b4043b0b8297e379bc559ab33b6ae9c7a9b4ef6519d3baee53270f0c0dd3d960"
            },
            "custom_data": { "currency": "GBP", "value": "30", "content_ids": ["3268"], "num_items": "1", "content_type": "product", "content_name": "BASEBALL CAP" }
        }
    ]
}
```